# Saving / accessing fields from Class methods (Django)

Tags: django

Appologies for the beginner question and/or stupidity - I'm learning as I go.... I'm trying to pass a user entered url of a PubMed article to access the metadata for that article. I'm using the following code, but I cannot access anything form the save method in he 'Entry' model. For example in my html form I can display {{entry.date_added }} in a form but not {{ entry.title}}. I suspect it's a simple answer but not obvious to me. Thanks for any help.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import pubmed_lookup
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

class Topic(models.Model):
    """Broad topic to house articles"""

    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """Enter and define article from topic"""

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_med_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        query = self.pub_med_url

        email = "david.hallsworth@hotmail.com"
        lookup = pubmed_lookup.PubMedLookup(query, email)
        publication = pubmed_lookup.Publication(lookup)

        self.title = strip_tags(publication.title)
        self.authors = publication.authors
        self.first_author = publication.first_author
        self.last_author = publication.last_author
        self.journal = publication.journal
        self.year = publication.year
        self.month = publication.month
        self.day = publication.day
        self.url = publication.url
        self.citation = publication.cite()
        self.mini_citation = publication.cite_mini()
        self.abstract = strip_tags(publication.abstract)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'articles'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {} - {} - {} [{}]".format(self.year,
                                               self.first_author, self.journal, self.title, str(self.pmid), )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django ORM, you have to manually specify all fields that need to be saved. Simply saving it as `self.foo = bar` in the save method is stored in the Entry instance object (=in memory), but not in the database. That is, there is no persistence. Specify all the fields that need to be saved in the model and run `python manage.py makemigrations`,`python manage.py migrate`. Assigning fields to the model is actually the task of designing the relational database.

```py
class Entry(models.Model):
    """Enter and define article from topic"""

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_med_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    title = models.CharField(...)
    authors = models.CharField(...)
    ...


    def assign_some_data_from_pubmed(self):

        email = "david.hallsworth@hotmail.com"
        lookup = pubmed_lookup.PubMedLookup(query, email)
        publication = pubmed_lookup.Publication(lookup)

        self.title = strip_tags(publication.title)
        self.authors = publication.authors
        self.first_author = publication.first_author
        self.last_author = publication.last_author
        self.journal = publication.journal
        self.year = publication.year
        self.month = publication.month
        self.day = publication.day
        self.url = publication.url
        self.citation = publication.cite()
        self.mini_citation = publication.cite_mini()
        self.abstract = strip_tags(publication.abstract)
```

Usage:

```py
entry = Entry(...)
entry.assign_some_data_from_pubmed()
entry.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. Having saved to the instance how do I then add that into the field. I understand that I'll have to define field and migrate, but when I tried something similar outside save definition it wouldn't work. Much appreciated!

Comment: From a modular point of view, it may be better to subtract the logic that gets data from PubMed inside the `save()` function into another function in the model. I prefer to call a function that assigns values to an instance and call the `save()` method, which is not overridden.This allows you to separate the logic you store in the database from the logic that pulls data from PubMed.

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me in the right direction; I did something slightly different in the end that works for me.